# Referring to columns by their names in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have three columns of data. I've named column A, "Short," column B "Long," and column C: "Position."

In my VBA code, I refer to data in Column C as: Range("C"&i) (where i is the row number).

How do I refer to column C as I've titled it in my macro?

Any suggestions are welcome, thanks!

This is my current code:

```
Sub NestedIf()
i = 2

Dim uLimit As Integer
Dim lLimit As Integer

uLimit = Range("e" & 1)
lLimit = Range("e" & 2)

Do
    If Range("c" & i) >= 0 Then
        If Abs(Range("c" & i)) <= uLimit Then
            If Abs(Range("c" & i)) >= lLimit Then
                Range("b" & i) = Abs(Range("c" & i))
            Else
                Range("b" & i) = lLimit
            End If
        Else
            Range("b" & i) = uLimit
        End If
    Else
        Range("b" & i) = 0
    End If

    If Range("c" & i) <= 0 Then
        If Abs(Range("c" & i)) <= uLimit Then
            If Abs(Range("c" & i)) >= lLimit Then
                Range("a" & i) = Abs(Range("c" & i))
            Else
                Range("a" & i) = lLimit
            End If
    Else
        Range("a" & i) = uLimit
    End If
Else
    Range("a" & i) = 0
End If

    i = i + 1
Loop Until IsEmpty(Range("c" & i))


End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Reading [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will help you get an answer sooner. Remember, this isn't a code-writing service, so post what you've got & we can help you fix it.

Comment: did you try Range("Short")?

Comment: You can refer to range(C & i) using Cells(i,3) - row i, column 3 (for a single cell).

    
When you say you've named them - do you mean a **Named Range** in which case @John comment should work.

Comment: @JohnColeman :Hey, yeah I've tried that and I get the following error:

"Run-time error '1004':

Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

Comment: @starter1011 what do you mean by "named" in "I named Column A 'Short'"? I assumed that you meant you were using named ranges, but it sounds like you just entered the value "Short" in the first cell. To name the range -- you need to select the range you want to name, navigate to the formulas tab, and click on "Define Name"

Comment: @JohnColeman : Yes I named it, as in, I defined it as you said.

Comment: @starter1011 check spelling if it is still giving you that error. Open up the name manager and see what you have. It is maybe possible that the name has the wrong scope e.g. it is scoped as a sheet1 name and you are trying to use it in sheet2.

Answer (score 1):

So long as your data is within a table (these can be defined with Ctrl+T), you could reference cells with:

```
TableName[ColumnName]
```

For instance, if your table was called `DataTable`, you could use `DataTable[Short]` to get the *Short* column.

Usage in VBA would be: `Range("DataTable[Short]")`

More information is available [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e).